# How to pass parameter to function using in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

In the traditional way to add event listener:

```
function getComboA(sel) {
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
}

<select id="comboA" onchange="getComboA(this)">
<option value="">Select combo</option>
<option value="Value1">Text1</option>
<option value="Value2">Text2</option>
<option value="Value3">Text3</option>
</select>
```

But I wanted to adapt to the `addEventListener` way:

```
productLineSelect.addEventListener('change',getSelection(this),false);

function getSelection(sel){
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
}
```

It doesn't work because I can't pass any parameter in `getSelection()` as the second parameter in `addEventListener` method? As far as I know I can only use the function name without parenthesises.

Any idea?

BTW, please look at [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12015540/456218) about `console.log` doesn't work in Safari 6.0 Developer Inspector, I can't write any output in the console, which is frustrating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass an extra argument to a callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802071/pass-an-extra-argument-to-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

No need to pass anything in. The function used for `addEventListener` will automatically have `this` bound to the current element. Simply use `this` in your function:

```
productLineSelect.addEventListener('change', getSelection, false);

function getSelection() {
    var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dJ4Wm/

---

If you want to pass arbitrary data to the function, wrap it in your own anonymous function call:

```
productLineSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    foo('bar');
}, false);

function foo(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4Gun/

---

If you want to set the value of `this` manually, you can use [the `call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call the function:

```
var self = this;
productLineSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    getSelection.call(self);
    // This'll set the `this` value inside of `getSelection` to `self`
}, false);

function getSelection() {
    var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: great! perfect answer! Could you point out what kind of mechanism of javascript that pass a function name(I mean without parenthesises) to other function? this's really interesting to me

Comment: Invaluable answer.

Comment: In your second example, how would you later remove that event listener? The function is anonymous.

Comment: I liked the idea of passing parameters to a function by wrapping it in an anonymous function in your second example, but is there any other way of doing this? Something like what the OP had posted in his question?

Answer (score 15):

In the first line of your JS code:

```
select.addEventListener('change', getSelection(this), false);
```

you're **invoking getSelection** by placing `(this)` behind the function reference. That is most likely not what you want, because you're now passing the return value of that call to addEventListener, instead of a reference to the actual function itself.

---

In a function invoked by `addEventListener` the value for `this` will automatically be set to the object the listener is attached to, `productLineSelect` in this case.

If that is what you want, you can just pass the function reference and `this` will in this example be `select` in invocations from addEventListener:

```
select.addEventListener('change', getSelection, false);
```

If that *is not* what you want, you'd best [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) your value for this to the function you're passing to `addEventListener`:

```
var thisArg = { custom: 'object' };
select.addEventListener('change', getSelection.bind(thisArg), false);
```

The `.bind` part is also a call, but this call just returns the same function we're calling `bind` on, with the value for `this` inside that function scope **fixed** to `thisArg`, effectively overriding the dynamic nature of this-binding.

---

To get to your actual question: *"How to pass parameters to function in addEventListener?"*

You would have to use an additional function definition:

```
var globalVar = 'global';

productLineSelect.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var localVar = 'local';
    getSelection(event, this, globalVar, localVar);
}, false);
```

Now we pass the event object, a reference to the value of `this` inside the callback of addEventListener, a variable defined and initialised inside that callback, and a variable from outside the entire addEventListener call to your own `getSelection` function.

---

We also might again have an object of our choice to be `this` inside the outer callback:

```
var thisArg = { custom: 'object' };
var globalVar = 'global';

productLineSelect.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var localVar = 'local';
    getSelection(event, this, globalVar, localVar);
}.bind(thisArg), false);
```

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey Westerkamp, your answer was helpful beause of you explained it in details!

Comment: This answer seems the best but could be improved by mentioning that creating the bound version creates a "new" function. Saving that in a variable and passing that function will also allow the use of removeEventListener. For more information see @bens aswer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565471/removing-event-listener-which-was-added-with-bind

Answer (score 7):

When you use `addEventListener`, `this` will be bound automatically.  So if you want a reference to the element on which the event handler is installed, just use `this` from within your function:

```
productLineSelect.addEventListener('change',getSelection,false);

function getSelection(){
    var value = sel.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
}
```

If you want to pass in some other argument from the context where you call `addEventListener`, you can use a closure, like this:

```
productLineSelect.addEventListener('change', function(){ 
    // pass in `this` (the element), and someOtherVar
    getSelection(this, someOtherVar); 
},false);

function getSelection(sel, someOtherVar){
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
    alert(someOtherVar);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `this` value you want is the just the object that you bound the event handler to, then `addEventListener()` already does that for you.  When you do this:

```
productLineSelect.addEventListener('change', getSelection, false);
```

the `getSelection` function will already be called with `this` set to the object that the event handler was bound to.  It will also be passed an argument that represents the event object which has all sorts of object information about the event.

```
function getSelection(event) {
    // this will be set to the object that the event handler was bound to
    // event is all the detailed information about the event
}
```

---

If the desired `this` value is some other value than the object you bound the event handler to, you can just do this:

```
var self = this;
productLineSelect.addEventListener('change',function() {
    getSelection(self)
},false);
```

By way of explanation:

1. You save away the value of `this` into a local variable in your other event handler.
2. You then create an anonymous function to pass addEventListener.
3. In that anonymous function, you call your actual function and pass it the saved value of `this`.