# JavaScript addEventListener function syntax

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, addeventlistener

I am having trouble understanding why the function parameter of the event listener isn't accepting just the function. Here's the code:

Variables are declared:

```
var spanJS = document.getElementById("spanJS")
var txtPlayers = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPlayers")
var txtAmount = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAmount")
```

Then associate the event listeners:

```
txtAmount.addEventListener("keyup", UpdateTotals())
txtPlayers.addEventListener("keyup", UpdateTotals())
```

Then the function:

```
function UpdateTotals() {
      ... 
}
```

This is the whole code. The problem is, when i run it, it executes UpdateTotals() without any keyup event, and the listeners don't work.

If i do the following change, it works like intended:

```
txtAmount.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
UpdateTotals()
})
txtPlayers.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
UpdateTotals()
})
```

Can anyone explain me why i can't just put the function's name, i have to "child" it in another function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the event listeners by removing the `()` at the end of the handler names, like so:

```
txtAmount.addEventListener("keyup", UpdateTotals);
```

This is to pass the *reference* of the function `UpdateTotals`, and not *run* the function `UpdateTotals()`. The latter will actually run the function immediately, and pass in the return value of the function.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses) about the idea of JavaScript function references (without parentheses).

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, UpdateTotals() is the value of the function when called without passing arguments, while UpdateTotals is the function itself

So you want:

```
txtAmount.addEventListener("keyup", UpdateTotals)
txtPlayers.addEventListener("keyup", UpdateTotals)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the parentheses within the event listeners.

Change:

```
txtAmount.addEventListener("keyup", UpdateTotals())
txtPlayers.addEventListener("keyup", UpdateTotals())
```

to:

```
txtAmount.addEventListener("keyup", UpdateTotals)
txtPlayers.addEventListener("keyup", UpdateTotals)
```