# How the function is used without parenthesis in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am not able to understand how this `addItem()` and `removeItem()` is called without parenthesis in `addEventListener('click', addItem)`.

```
var addButton = document.getElementById('add');
addButton.addEventListener('click', addItem);

var removeButton = document.getElementById('remove');
removeButton.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

function addItem(){
    console.log('Add Button clicked');
}

function removeItem(){
    console.log('Remove Button clicked');
}
```

Comment: That's a reference to the function.  If you do `var anotherAddItem = addItem;` then you can execute `anotherAddItem()` in the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript addEventListener function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933573/javascript-addeventlistener-function-syntax)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in this context, `addItem` is used as a *function reference* rather than the return value of the function.

If you did this:

```
addButton.addEventListener('click', addItem());
```

Then `addItem` would be executed straight away, and whenever `addButton` was clicked, the return value of `addItem` (which is `undefined`) would be called. This would result in an error, because `undefined` is not a function.

Here, you're saying *when I click `addButton`, lookup the function reference I passed, and execute it.*

You can also write this two different ways:

```
addButton.addEventListener('click', "addItem()");
addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addItem();
});
```

Both of the above will still result in the same output as your original code.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are passing the function as an argument/parameter to the `addEventListener()` method. If you add the parathesis, the function would execute straight away and that is not what you want. You're telling the `addEventListener()` which function to execute *when the event is fired*.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without parentheses you're not actually calling the function. A
function name without the parentheses is a reference to the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is core js functionality. You can read about this [here.](https://codeburst.io/javascript-functions-understanding-the-basics-207dbf42ed99)

> Functions are function objects. In JavaScript, anything that is not a
>   primitive type ( undefined , null , boolean , number , or string ) is
>   an object. Objects in JavaScript are extremely versatile. Because of
>   this, we can even pass a function as a parameter into another function

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching an event listener and it will call the function
If you add the parentesis inside the callback you will recive error because you exec the call

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is the `addEventlistener` method function. You can define the function in global, without add parentheses in the second argument addEventlistener.