# Checkbox event listener not firing

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

I have a number of checkboxes in my page. These checkboxes are used to toggle the visibility of a layer through a Javascript function.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_0">Aerial<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_1">Aerial (Labels)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_2">Road<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_3">Road On Demand<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_4">OSM Layer<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_5">WMS Layer<br>
```

I have an event listener for each of the checkboxes to check for a change, and if it changes, the `toggleOpacity(value, el_id)` function is called which takes 2 arguments, `value` - the checkbox number/layer position in the mapLayers array, and `el_id` - the checkbox id.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_0').addEventListener('change', toggleOpacity(0,'op_checkbox_0'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_1').addEventListener('change', toggleOpacity(1,'op_checkbox_1'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_2').addEventListener('change', toggleOpacity(2,'op_checkbox_2'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_3').addEventListener('change', toggleOpacity(3,'op_checkbox_3'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_4').addEventListener('change', toggleOpacity(4,'op_checkbox_4'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_5').addEventListener('change', toggleOpacity(5,'op_checkbox_5'));
});
```

The function toggles the visibility of the layer by changing the opacity. It also assigns a Z-value of 1 and all other layers to 0 so that the last toggled layer will be on top (visible). `mapLayers.length` is equal to 6, the same as the number of checkboxes.

```
function toggleOpacity(value, el_id){
    console.log('value='+value+' id='+el_id);
    if(document.getElementById(el_id).checked == true){
        console.log('true');
        for(let i = 0; i<mapLayers.length;i++){
        mapLayers[i].set('zIndex', 0);
        }
        mapLayers[value].set('opacity', 1);     
        mapLayers[value].set('zIndex', 1);
        console.log('Box ' + value + 'on!');
    } else if(document.getElementById(el_id).checked == false) {
        console.log('false');;
        mapLayers[value].set('opacity', 0);
    }
}
```

`mapLayers` is the layer array of the OpenLayers map. Each position corresponds to a different layer. The function doesn't seem to be firing when I toggle a checkbox, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Where is `mapLayers()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not adding an event, you are calling it instead.

so change

```
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_0').addEventListener('change', toggleOpacity(0,'op_checkbox_0'));
```

> To

```
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_0').addEventListener('change', ()=> toggleOpacity(0,'op_checkbox_0'));
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_0').addEventListener('change', ()=> toggleOpacity(0,'op_checkbox_0'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_1').addEventListener('change', ()=> toggleOpacity(1,'op_checkbox_1'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_2').addEventListener('change', ()=> toggleOpacity(2,'op_checkbox_2'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_3').addEventListener('change', ()=> toggleOpacity(3,'op_checkbox_3'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_4').addEventListener('change', ()=> toggleOpacity(4,'op_checkbox_4'));
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_5').addEventListener('change', ()=> toggleOpacity(5,'op_checkbox_5'));
});

function toggleOpacity(value, el_id){
   console.log(el_id + "changed")
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_0">Aerial<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_1">Aerial (Labels)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_2">Road<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_3">Road On Demand<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_4">OSM Layer<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_5">WMS Layer<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually in code you are not passing a `function` in as ur second parameter in `addEventListener`. `toggleOpacity(value, el_id)` will return and a value and it will be set as variable `undefined` but not `toggleOpacity`

```
document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_0').addEventListener('change', ()=>{
        toggleOpacity(0,'op_checkbox_0'));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling `toggleOpacity(value, el_id)` and it doesn't return a thing.
So you passing `undefined` as a callback to your addEventListener.
Try like this:

```
document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_0').addEventListener('change', (event)=>{ 
   toggleOpacity(0,'op_checkbox_0');
});
```

You need to pass a function. If you call the function you pass the return value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  document.querySelector('#op_checkbox_0').addEventListener('change', function() {
        toggleOpacity(0,'op_checkbox_0')
  });
```

And analogically for every other listener