# Can I reuse javascript functions in multiple event listeners?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I want to reause one long function in multiple event listeners.

Is there a way I can reuse javascript functions in multiple event listeners (without jQuery or other libraries).

I've tried a few things.

```
function one(){
    console.log("not supposed to show until I press the variable containing num1")
};


num1.addEventListener('click', one());
```

Runs the function at the beginning and doesn't run on click

```
num1.addEventListener('click', function one(){
    console.log("oops")
});
num2.addEventListener('click', one());
```

Runs when I press num1 doesn't work when I pess num2

```
const one = () => {console.log("Still not working")}
num1.addEventListener('click', one());
```

same issue as with the first example.

I want to reause one long function in multiple event listeners.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like this `num1.addEventListener("click", one); num2.addEventListener("click", one);`
With `function one(...){...}` previously declared

Answer (score 0):

you should provide a function to be called by the event listener, but by doing doing `one()` you are not providing function instead providing whatever is returning by that function.

like [@Luis Barajas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10199179/luis-barajas) mentioned, do `num1.addEventListener("click", one)`

Answer (score 0):

`one()` return `undefined` you are passing `undefined` instead of callback.You can pass a function and call `one()` inside it.

```js
let num1 = document.querySelector('#num1');
let num2 = document.querySelector('#num2');


function one(){
  console.log("Its working ");
}
num1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  one()
});
num2.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  one()
});
```

```html
<button id="num1">Num 1</button>
<button id="num2">Num 2</button>
```