# Combining EventListener and Closures in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, addeventlistener

I am trying to use a closure, to call a function when the user scrolls on the document in JavaScript.
Therefore i create the constant `scroll` and call the inner function via `scroll()` when the event 'scroll' happens. 
I don't get an error when I'm trying to do this with the code below but the inner function doesn't get called for some reason.

```
const scroll = scrollEvent();
document.addEventListener("scroll", scroll());

function scrollEvent() {
    debugger;
    var positions = {pos1: 3, pos2: 5};
    return function() {
        loadContent(positions);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost the correct code. But the closure is already created when you create `scroll` variable and call `scrollEvent` (after that `scroll` contains a reference to the returned function), hence you have to pass only `scroll` to `addEventListener`, because calling it just returns `undefined`.

Another way is to omit `scroll` variable, and call `scrollEvent` in the argument, like so:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollEvent());
```

Now `scrollEvent` returns the function to use as an event listener, and the closure is created, and `positions` is available in the event handler when the event fires.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed the problem :)