# Why is my function running by itself, instead of on a button-click?

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a timer which counts down 2 hours. I want the timer to run only when a button, *item1*, is pressed. However, right now, the timer is running immediately when the page opens. I think it's something to do with the interval, but, I'm not sure what to change.

How can I change this so that it only runs when the button is clicked? (And the timer stops when the button is clicked a second time).

Here's the code:

```
var itemClick = document.getElementById('item1');

itemClick.addEventListener('click', function(){
    itemHandler();
})

var count = 7200;
var counter = setInterval(itemHandler, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function itemHandler() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    document.getElementById("item1-label").innerHTML = hours + " hour(s) " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds remaining.";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't want the interval.

Comment: Your function isn't calling itself. It's being called only by the event handler and the `setInterval` timer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to

Comment: @Azoel - No, that's not happening above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my bad, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function isn't calling itself. It's being called only by the event handler and the `setInterval` timer.

It sounds like you didn't intend to start the interval timer immediately. If that's the case, move the code starting the interval timer into the event handler:

```
var itemClick = document.getElementById('item1');
var counter = 0;
itemClick.addEventListener('click', function(){
    itemHandler(); // Include this if you want it to run right away, since the
                   //  first timer callback will take a second
    counter = setInterval(itemHandler, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
});
```

You might also want to disable the button or something while the timer is running, or perhaps allow cancelling with another button click.

Disabling the button:

```
var itemClick = document.getElementById('item1');
var counter = 0;
itemClick.addEventListener('click', function(){
    itemClick.disabled = true;
    counter = setInterval(itemHandler, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
});
```

and in `itemHandler`:

```
if (count == -1) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    itemClick.diabled = false; // *** Added
    return;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but, yeah, I'll need to disable the button; if I keep pressing the button, it increases the timer speed by 1s. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = null;

itemClick.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (counter) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        counter = null;
    } else {
        counter = setInterval(itemHandler, 1000);
    }
})
```

Start and stop the interval based on clicking the button, only.

Comment: Got a "counter is not defined" error. When I created a variable for it, nothing happened. 