# Fetching data but "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

I try to fetch some data from the https://randomuser.me/api/  . I wanna take an random user gender but i don't know why my function doesn't do it and i get this error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

My code:

```
const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState('');
         
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(setFetchData)
        .then(console.log(fetchData.results[0].gender));
```

Comment: you are trying to access state immediately after it is set . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately

Comment: You should make the API call in a useEffect.

Comment: @selbie i think yes, because i did the same thing on my last project and it went well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchData` doesn't get updated when `setFetchData` is called.  Remember, it's just a local variable that got assigned when you invoked `useState`.  It doesn't magically get updated until the next call to your function. And even then, `setState` is asynchronous, so it might not change immediately.

This is what you likely really want.

```
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json)=> {
         setFetchData(json);
         console.log(json.results[0].gender);
     });
```

I tried it out locally and it worked for me.

Also, as an aside.  For robustness, so you don't throw an exception on a console statement when the response is completely unexpected:

```
if (json && json.results && json.results[0]) {
    console.log(json.results[0].gender);
}
```