# Why does "click" event happen on load when I use addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseclick-event

I used document.querySelectorAll() get a NodeList of all buttons in the HTML file, then iterated through each button to add an event listener to each button to listen for a click on each button.

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener("click", console.log("Button clicked"));
});
```

However, on load, all buttons are clicked, and I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Comment: the second argument of `addEventListener` must be a function - replace `console.log("Button clicked")` with `() => console.log("Button clicked")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function attached should be a handler, executed by the event listener when required. In your given example, the `console.log()` is called when the *foreach* function is called.

Change your handler function to accept an argument, then perform your `console.log`:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener("click", function(ev){ console.log('Clicked'); });
});
```

I used a `function` here for readability but it can be any valid callback.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener#javascript