# Javascript Class set private var on public function

Tags: javascript, es6-class

can i set variables on the scope of the class to be used later?

example

```
class TestClass {
    #key = '';
    #reference = '';
    #onReturn = () => {};

    constructor({ key } = {}) {
        this.#key = key || this.#key;
        this.#onReturn = onReturn || this.#onReturn;
    }

    login(username, password) {
        this.#submit(username, password);
    };

    #submit(username, password) {
        fetch(
            `/login/${this.#key}`,
        )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                this.#handleResponse(json);
            })
    };

    #handleResponse(json) {
        this.#reference = json.reference;
        this.#onReturn();
    };

    token() {
        console.log(this.#key, this.#reference); // "blabla", empty
    };
};

const Test = new TestClass({ // initializing the class
    key: 'blabla',
    onReturn: tokenSubmit
});

const onLoginSubmit = () => {
    Test.login(username, password); // running a fetch which will set a private var
};

const tokenSubmit = () => {
    Test.token(); // private var returns empty
};
```

which has two public methods **login** and **token**
where the **token** should log the **key** and the **reference**

as a result i do get the **key** which was set on the constructor
but the **reference** which was set while handling a fetch returns empty

Comment: `#submit` calls `fetch` which is asynchronous. So `LoginModule.login()` hasn't finished by the time you call `LoginModule.token()` [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: @VLAZ on the actual scenario the "token" is only called after the "login" returns

Comment: Why do you use { json } ? That syntax is meant to be used for object destruction. Are you sure that you have json child to use from that argument object in #handleReference

Comment: @kalle that's just as an example I've had other stuff in there, I'll edit the question

Comment: @Kup that's not what you show here. And the result you get is consistent with trying to handle async code before it completes.

Comment: @VLAZ i've edited the question now to better emulate the scenario

Comment: You could return the chained promise from `#submit()`, then also return it from `login()` so you can do: `Test.login(username, password).then(() => Test.token())` or `await Test.login(username, password)` and `Test.token()` the line below.

Comment: @3limin4t0r it's two separate forms for the user. the first would trigger and email with the token which the user should submit on the second form

Comment: It doesn't matter too much, but be aware that `response.json()` doesn't actually resolve with JSON.

Comment: @Kup [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/dohuzad/1/edit?js,console). I also had to make a fair few changes so the code worked. Please make sure to supply a [mcve] that clearly demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @VLAZ apologies for that, i did try using the [emulator](https://jsbin.com/meriwuweba/edit?js,console) and it's fine, my problem apparently resides on using it on react, because that last call just doesn't pickup the var added to the scope by the login method. will try a different way, thanks

Comment: React is still just JavaScript. It doesn't change the rules of how the language is interpreted and executions are made.

Comment: @VLAZ apparently the issue comes from the **handleSubmit** from **useForm** (react-hook-form) for some reason the class just losses the scope set on the first method called

Comment: @Kup you mean the age old problem [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484)?

Comment: as in if i simply use `onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); onTokenSubmit();}}` and not `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onTokenSubmit)}` the scope is there

Comment: @VLAZ haven't tried using the old way, i was just playing around with class thinking it would have the sabe behavior, but in sum, yes, it's probably the arrow functions that are screwing this up

Comment: In that case it's [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16310423). You need to provide *a function reference* as a handler, not *call a function*. Would have taken few minutes to diagnose *if your example was representative*.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @vlaz's comment, try the following test code:

```js
async function test() {
    const Test = new TestClass({ key: 'blabla' }); // initializing the 
class
    await LoginModule.login({ username, password }); // running a fetch which will set a private var
    LoginModule.token(); // private var returns empty
}
```

The addition of `await` waits for the `fetch` to complete before proceeding to the next line, calling `LoginModule.token()`.

For this to work, you'll also need to modify `#submit` to return `fetch`'s promise:

```js
    #submit({ username, password }) {
        return fetch(
            `/login/${this.#key}`,
        )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                this.#handleResponse({ json });
            })
    };
```

Comment: i've edited the question now to better emulate the scenario