# declaring function from addEventListner or alone

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

```
    document.getElementById("somethings").addEventListener("click", function() {
        // code code code
    });

    // ============= or like this =============

    document.getElementById("somethings").addEventListener("click", fun);
    
    function fun(){
        // code code code
    }
```

As a newbie i ask, is one of those more "correct" then the other?

Comment: The second one is wrong `.addEventListener("click", fun())` should be `.addEventListener("click", fun)`. See [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16310423). Other than that, there isn't anything inherently "more" or "less" right between the two.

Comment: It's a callback.

Comment: You are passing the result of a function call and not a function, so your code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to preference, but declaring functions to have your logic scoped separately from the event is a good practice, also I have noticed that you are calling the function instead of passing the reference of a function:

Your code:

```
function fun(){
  // code code code
}

document.getElementById("somethings").addEventListener("click", fun());
```

Do this:

```
function fun(){
  // code code code
}

document.getElementById("somethings").addEventListener("click", fun);
```