# Pass index to be accessible in out side function addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function, and need use the index from `foreach`loop, example:

```
window.onload = function()
{   
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('image_add_product')).forEach(function(element,index)
    {
        element.addEventListener("change", input_change(index), false);
    });
};
```

And in `input_change` function i need the `index`

```
function input_change(index)
{
    alert(index);
    alert(this.type);
}
```

I dont know why, when window load, the `change` is automatic trigger! Even not change anything. See below:

```js
window.onload = function()
{   
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('image_add_product')).forEach(function(element,index)
    {
        element.addEventListener("change", input_change(index), false);
    });
};

function input_change(index)
{   
    alert(this.type);
    alert(index);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" class="image_add_product">one
<input type="file" class="image_add_product">two
<input type="file" class="image_add_product">tree
```

Whats happens?

Comment: `element.addEventListener("change", function() { input_change(index); }, false);` (you're passing the result of the function call i.e. `undefined` but you're supposed to pass a function)

Comment: Duplicate: [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Comment: Tks for atention, exact answer @ChrisG