# What is exactly the event object?

Tags: javascript, object, events, dom-events

What is an event object? When is it executed? Why do we have it?
For example:

1. when we use an anonymous function as in this example, the event object will not be `renderPosts()` function.

   ````
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => renderPosts());

   const renderPosts = async () => {
     let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/posts?_sort=likes&_order=desc';
     const res = await fetch(uri);
     const container = document.querySelector(".blogs");```
   ````
2. when we do not use anonymous function as in this example, the event object will be `renderPosts()` function.

   ````
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',renderPosts());

   const renderPosts = async () => {
     let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/posts?_sort=likes&_order=desc';
     const res = await fetch(uri);
     const container = document.querySelector(".blogs");```
   ````

I do not see the difference and not really understand it.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) has some useful information on the event object. Also, objects aren't "executed", functions are.

Comment: I think this might help you understand, https://www.30secondsofcode.org/articles/s/javascript-arrow-function-event-listeners, your callback is different in 1. and 2., that is the reason that Event is different. And Event is same as Event Object, if that is confusing.

Comment: For `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',renderPosts());` see: [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272) and [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16310423)

Comment: In the second scenario you've just called the _renderPosts_ function, so it can not be added as an _event listener_ callback. Also event object is totally different from event listener callback function. You can check this out : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss, thank you so much; you really solved all my confusions. All the resources are very helpful.

Comment: Credit to @VLAZ and others here for most of it, I just formatted the question a bit :)