# Why function calling using onclick only works when nested in another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why do functions nested in an anonymous function wait for button click (as it should), but when the function is not nested it runs on page load without waiting for button click?

Working example:

```
btn1.onclick = function() {cityChoice(1)};
     //code works only on button click as expected
```

Not working example:

```
btn1.onclick = cityChoice(1);
     //function runs on pageload without waiting for button click?
```

Any links to documentation/articles are welcome, as I could not find them on Google nor on StackOverflow that explained this.

Coding language: JavaScript (vanilla) 
Skill level: Beginner 
Editor: Visual Studio Code 
OS: Windows 7

Comment: In the second example you are not assigning a function to `btn1.onclick`; you are calling `cityChoice` with the arg `1` and returning the result which you are assigning to `btn1.onclick`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Answer (score 0):

`btn1.onclick = cityChoice(1);` isn't a nested function. You merely called the `cityChoice` function and its return value saved as `onclick` property of variable `btn1`.

There are several ways you can achieve the same thing to bind listener to an event:

`btn1.onclick = function() { }` <-- anonymous function

`btn1.onclick = () => { }` <-- arrow function

---

In conclusion:

`btn1.onclick = cityChoice(1)` <-- cityChoice function is invoked and its value is saved to btn1.onclick

Ref:

[Anonymous functions in JS](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-anonymous-functions/)

[Arrow functions in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

cityChoice is a function and I assume you're trying to pass it your default argument `1` the problem you're seeing is that you're *invoking* cityChoice in your second example and assigning the result of `cityChoice(1)` to onclick instead of registering an event handler. This I assume would return a normal javascript object. onclick needs to be an event handler (any function anonymous or not)

Answer (score 0):

When you use this `cityChoice(1);` without nested function.

Javascript understand it like you type it without `onclick` event
It's like you call it on page load.

But `function` statment assign new function when called it call `cityChoice(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

All the event handlers (like onClick) expects a Function reference (1st option) and not the Function result (2nd option). Here is the [official document from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#syntax) which explains it nicely.

When the event (for example, click) is triggered, it executes the Function you're passing to it. So if you pass a return value from a Function to onClick event, it won't be able to execute it, and you would get an error.

I hope this explains the concept in simple terms.