# Javascript function is not clicking upon running Niether Showing any error? Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

`Hey I was making a function but it seems onclick function is not working in google chrome extension and showing me the error

Basically my function is used to click all the checkboxes when I click on the button through add event listener which i read in stackoverflow here is the link of that post [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

After building that the thing is not working not sure what to do next

HTML CODE:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="body.css">
    <title>Linkedin Extension</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div class="main">
        <H1 class="h1">Select All</H1>
        <p class="p1">This is to Select all the checkboxes</p>
        <button type="button" id="select-all" >Run me</button>
    </div>

</main>
<footer class="end">Made with Love</footer>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("select-all").addEventListener("click", selectAll);
  });

  function selectAll(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("invitee-picker-connections-result-item__checkbox");
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
    {
    inputs[i].click();
    }
    }
```

Let me know how this will code ran when I click on the html button

Here is the screenshot attached what it will do when it will run
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pfj4.png)

I want to run this code in an extension when I will click the button`

Comment: You need to inject the function into the web page using chrome.scripting.executeScript. Also remove lines 1 and 3 in your script.js because it already runs after DOMContentLoaded. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Sorry man new to this things have'nt done that before Still unable to do that

Comment: See [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67227376).

Comment: `const tabId = getselectAll();
chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: {tabId: selectAll()},
      files: ['script.js'],
    },
    () => { var btn = document.getElementById("select");
    btn.addEventListener("click", selectAll);
    function selectAll(){
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("invitee-picker-connections-result-item__checkbox");
        for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
        {
        inputs[i].click();
        }
        } });`