# OOP "Classes" and DOM manipulation with JavaScript, undefined element

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constructor, dom-manipulation

This is my first personal project using JavaScript to make a website dynamic. I don't feel utterly lost, but after a few days I will take a knee at being "stuck". I have a grid container containing 6 items which I would like to attach a "click" `eventListener` to. Essentially I am using Classes and Constructors to organize my code, and my problem likely lies in inadequate familiarity with how to compose the code properly.

```
// these are the `grid items`
function mapContainers() {
    let values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
    let gridItems = values.map((element) => {
        return document.querySelector(`.item${element}`);
    });
    return gridItems;
}

// this is my GridButton Class
class GridButton {
    constructor(button, direction) {
        this.button = button;
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    // Getter
    get whenClicked() {
        return this.button.addEventListener("click", popUp(`${this.direction}`));
    }
    // Method
    popUp(direction) {
        gridContainer.style.zIndex = "-1";
        gridContainer.style.opacity = "0.2";
        dogBone.style.display = "block";
        dogBone.animate(
            {
                transform: "scale(0, 0)",
                transformOrigin: `${this.direction}`
            },
            {
                transform: "scale(1, 1)"
            },
            {
                duration: 400,
                iterations: 1
            }
        );
    }
}

// this is my init()
function init() {
    // Call functions here
    const gridItems = mapContainers();
    const dogWalking = new GridButton(gridItems[0], "top left");
    const dayCare = new GridButton(gridItems[1], "top right");
    const boarding = new GridButton(gridItems[2], "left");
    const bath = new GridButton(gridItems[3], "right");
    const parties = new GridButton(gridItems[4], "bottom left");
    const petWasteRemoval = new GridButton(gridItems[2], "left");
    dogWalking.whenClicked();
    dayCare.whenClicked();
    boarding.whenClicked();
    bath.whenClicked();
    parties.whenClicked();
    petWasteRemoval.whenClicked();
}

// variously defined variables:
const gridContainer = document.querySelector("services_grid_container");
const serviceElaboration = document.querySelector("service_elaboration");
const serviceElaborationText = document.querySelector("service_elaboration_text");
const dogBone = document.querySelector("dog-bone");
const dogBoneText = document.querySelector("dog-bonetext");

// running the init()
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

for some reason, the console logs an error:

```
script.js:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: popUp is not defined
    at get whenClicked [as whenClicked] (script.js:19:28)
    at HTMLDocument.init (script.js:51:16)
get whenClicked @ script.js:19
init @ script.js:51
```

I'm not sure why it is saying `popUp` is not defined. I do not mean to be airing out my dirty laundry, I'm just trying to understand! I'll keep trying to understand this in the meantime, but thank you for anyone who considers helping.

I tried consulting Chat GPT, and that didn't solve the problem. Chat GPT suggested adding the `eventListener` to the constructor, but I couldn't figure that out beyond its code which yielded the same error. I've contemplated integrating `popUp` into the constructor, but that seems like a dead-end. Finally I am utilizing stack overflow.

Comment: ``popUp(`${this.direction}`)`` -> ``this.popUp(`${this.direction}`)`` missing `this`. You always have to include it when referring to methods and properties of the current object. But moreover ``this.button.addEventListener("click", popUp(`${this.direction}`));`` should be ``this.button.addEventListener("click", () => this.popUp(`${this.direction}`));`` because otherwise you're *immediately calling* the function, instead of adding an event handler that would make the call when invoked. See [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16310423)

Comment: `popUp` in `addEventListener` parameter refers to `popUp` variable, not to the method of the instance. Notice also, that you should pass a reference to `addEventListener` rather than call the handler in the parameters.

Comment: Adding to the previous comments. `this.direction` in the `popUp` method will refer to the `direction` property on the button - because `this` changes when using it as a callback in `addEventListener`. Use an arrow function to implicitly bind `this` to the `GridButton` class: `popUp = (direction) => {}`

Comment: @EmielZuurbier  Arrow functions will help here, but there is actually no binding happening, as arrow function have no binding of their own.

Comment: `whenClicked` is a getter function, thus one does not explicitly call it as a method of a `GridButton` instance; instead one does access whatever `whenClicked` returns like ... `boarding.whenClicked`. In addition the return value of the `addEventListener` method equals the `undefined` value. Therefore `boarding.whenClicked`, with every access, does add yet another event listener to `this.button` and always returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

- The popup method wasn't found because you didn't use `this`, and you lost the scope to your class instance, you can fix it with an arrow function.
- You don't need to pass the direction to the popup method since we are inside a class instance, and the direction is a property.
- You can add the eventListener right away and you don't have to `return` it.
- You have to ask yourself if all the popup code has to be in each class instance, since the popup is not really a part of the grid item. It's also not so common to use global variables (container and dog bone) in a OOP class.

```
    // these are the `grid items`
    function mapContainers() {
      let values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
      let gridItems = values.map((element) => {
        return document.querySelector(`.item${element}`);
      });
      return gridItems;
    }
    
    // this is my GridButton Class
    class GridButton {
      constructor(button, direction) {
        this.button = button;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.button.addEventListener("click", () => this.popUp());
      }
    
      popUp() {
        console.log(`popup code for direction: ${this.direction}`)
    
        gridContainer.style.zIndex = "-1";
        gridContainer.style.opacity = "0.2";
        dogBone.style.display = "block";
        dogBone.animate({
          transform: "scale(0, 0)",
          transformOrigin: this.direction
        }, {
          transform: "scale(1, 1)"
        }, {
          duration: 400,
          iterations: 1
        });
      }
    }
    
    // create grid items
    function init() {
      const gridItems = mapContainers();
      const dogWalking = new GridButton(gridItems[0], "top left");
      const dayCare = new GridButton(gridItems[1], "top right");
      const boarding = new GridButton(gridItems[2], "left");
      const bath = new GridButton(gridItems[3], "right");
      const parties = new GridButton(gridItems[4], "bottom left");
      const petWasteRemoval = new GridButton(gridItems[5], "left");
    }
    
    const gridContainer = document.querySelector(".services_grid_container");
    const dogBone = document.querySelector(".dog-bone");
    init();
```

As a side note, if you want to learn more about using OOP classes with DOM manipulation, you can look at web components / custom elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components