# How to pass a JavaScript statement to a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass a complete JavaScript statement to a function to prevent typing the same code again. I am using a variable but this code does not seem to work. The HTML input is given below.

```js
var e2;
  e2 = document.getElementById("num2");
  e2.addEventListener('blur', checko(e2));

function checko(k){
   alert("Hey you have entered - "+k.value)
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="num2" placeholder="0">
```

This is just a small code of the web page I am building and to validate other inputs I would like to KEEP use a function.

Comment: Better duplicate target: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024483/how-to-pass-parameter-to-function-using-in-addeventlistener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change event to `change` and use `this.value` as parameter see Snippet. The behavior of `change` is that it has 3 distinct characteristics:

1. The `event.target` needs to be a form input (that includes `textarea` as well). ✔
2. It needs user input. ✔
3. It fires when the `event.target` has lost `focus` (a.k.a. `blur`). ✔

#### SNIPPET

```js
var e2 = document.getElementById("num2")

e2.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  checko(this.value);
}, false);

function checko(k) {
  alert("Hey you have entered - " + k);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="num2" placeholder="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to pass a complete JavaScript statement to a function

It seems you are trying to pass the value of `e2` which is the `id` of the DOM element

Also  `checko(e2)` will execute the function as soon as event is attached to the DOM.

Instead you need to delegate the event.

Beside you can also use [**Event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event) object to find out the target on which event is executed.

This snippet may be useful

```
var e2;
e2 = document.getElementById("num2");
e2.addEventListener('blur', checko);

function checko(event){
   alert("Hey you have entered - "+event.target.value)
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/nLr6ghhw/)

Answer (score 0):

You can' pass arguments directly when using `addEventListener` you can use `function() {yourfuncttion(args);}`

```
var e2;
e2 = document.getElementById("num2");
e2.addEventListener('blur', function () { 
 checko(e2) 
});

function checko(k) {
alert("Hey you have entered - " + k.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checko(){
 var e2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
 alert("Hey you have entered - "+e2);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="num2" placeholder="0" onblur="checko()">
```

You can also use `Onblur` Event Listener on direct field.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


Enter your lastname: <input type="text" id="firstname" >
Enter your fnmae : <input type="text" id="lastname">

<p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>

<script>

var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
firstname.addEventListener('blur', function() {
myFunction(firstname)   
});

var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
lastname.addEventListener('blur', function() {
myFunction(lastname)   
});

function myFunction(k){
   alert("Hey you have entered - "+k.value)
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```