# Why can't I pass arguments from my Event listener method this way to my function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My JS goes here `<input type='radio'id="Hero"/>`   the bunch of functions  below get the radio button get unchecked whenever it gets clicked even time

```
var hero=document.getElementById('Hero');

hero.addEventListener('onclick',"bye(this)");
  
function bye(this){
    var check=this.id; /////Here I am getting  the id of the element
    hoya(); 
   if(c%2==0){
    check.checked=false;
   }
}

function hoya(){
  ++c;
  return c; 
}
```

Comment: Because the second argument of `addEventListener` needs to be a function. `"bye(this)"` is not a function.

Comment: Sir it is a function you may look

Comment: No, it’s not a function. It’s a string.

Comment: Ok should i pass it without quotes

Comment: But sir if you say so i agree but in this case it works with quotes<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this.id)">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(elementId) {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x+elementId ;
}
</script>

Comment: `addEventListener` is not the same thing as an inline event listener (HTML attribute). Passing it without quotes also will not work, because `bye(this)` is also not a function. This is how you need to do it: [How to pass parameter to function using in addEventListener?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12024483/4642212).

Comment: @SuyashSrivastava When you add it in as an attribute to HTML that attribute is evaluated by the JavaScript parser. When you pass a function as a parameter within JavaScript it has to explicitly be a function, not a string.

Comment: @SuyashSrivastava It seems you are probably new to JS, as a suggestion, it is best to avoid inline events for a number of reasons. As evidenced by your confusion, code maintenance and clarity can suffer.

Comment: Check the docs for [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). `"bye(this)"` is a string, `bye(this)` is `undefined` because `bye` doesn’t return anything. `bye`, `function(){ bye(this); }`* and `bye.bind(this)` are functions (* in expression context). You want one of the three last ones.