# pass an argument in addeventlistener- javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I defined a function to change the elements attribute.
I want to pass an argument to this function in 'addEventListener' and this is my problem.

Here is the function :

```
function collapse (el) {
    var _cl = el.classList;
    _cl.add("box_size1");
    el.removeAttribute("id");
}
```

Here is main code :

```
window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("box_size2");
    el.addEventListener("click", collapse(???));
}
```

what shall I write instead of question marks ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameter to function using in addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024483/how-to-pass-parameter-to-function-using-in-addeventlistener)

Comment: Have you searched “JavaScript how to pass arguments to addEventListener” in Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need pass anything with function.Default `this` is bind in the function .Just call `this` inside the function instead of `el`

```js
window.onload = function() {
var el = document.getElementById("box_size2");
el.addEventListener("click", collapse);
}

function collapse() {
var _cl = this.classList;
_cl.add("box_size1");
this.removeAttribute("id");
console.log(this.outerHTML)
}
```

```html
<button id="box_size2">click</button>
```