# I don't understand why my global variable isn't updating?

Tags: javascript

I posted about this yesterday but I am still dumbfounded. 
I can't seem to figure out this problem. I want to update the parkEndpoint URL with a new value for the stateName variable when the user clicks on a state SVG. It keeps coming up as the original value in line 1.

I have tried looking in the console and after the function getStateName runs it does update the stateName variable, but when I console log the parkEndpoint variable after that function has run, it still shows the old variable, which I just set to nothing.

```
var stateName = "";
const alertEndpoint = ("https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/alerts? 
&limit=400&api_key=" + apikey );
var parkEndpoint = ("https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks? 
stateCode=" + stateName + "&limit=100&api_key=" + apikey);

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('path');
console.log(elements);

// add event listeners
elements.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click",  getStateName);

});


   function getStateName(nodeList){
   stateName = nodeList.path[0].id;
   outputStateName(stateName);

 }

   function outputStateName(stateName) {
   console.log(stateName);
   console.log(parkEndpoint);
  }
```

I just want it to update the stateName variable in the URL.

Comment: I don't see where you are passing `nodeList` to `getStateName` function. Shouldn't you be doing `el.addEventListener("click", getStateName(elements));`

Comment: What happens when you console.log( nodeList.path[0].id ); inside getStateName() ?

Comment: because once the string is evaluated it is done. It does not keep updating....

Comment: Won't affect your logic, but it's not normal to set the value of a variable within a get function. Setters are for setting, getters are for getting, following standard practice will help you.

Comment: Why no change the `parkEndpoint` a function and the stateName as param?

Comment: parkEndpoint is assgined value before the getStateName function is called. Therefore the value value of statename in parkEndpoint will be empty.
If initialized in outputStateName() function and checked, it will be proper

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024483/how-to-pass-parameter-to-function-using-in-addeventlistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statName variable is empty in the beginning and even after you are getting the state name from `stateName = nodeList.path[0].id;` the variable **parkEndpoint** is never being updated.

```
var stateName = '';
var parkEndpoint = parkEndpointUpdate();

function parkEndpointUpdate(){
   return `https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?
   stateCode=${stateName}&limit=100&api_key=${apikey}`
}

function getStateName(){
   stateName = nodeList.path[0].id;
   parkEndpoint = parkEndpointUpdate(); // This func will updated your variable of parkEndPont
   outputStateName(stateName);
}
```

Comment: I have made some changes to it after being verified for right answer pls check.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't update the value of `parkEndpoint`

In javascript, string are stored by reference. Meaning parkEndpoint references to the string defined L3, and is not reassigned later.

You need to reassign it in your getStateName function.