# How to pass value onclick in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can you pass a value with the click in JS like you can in HTML with `onclick="myFunction(value)"`

All methods I know:
`element.onclick = myFunction`, `element.addEventListner("click", myFunction)`
don't open up for passing a value with.

Comment: What about `element.addEventListener("click", function () { myFunction(value) })`?

Comment: what value you want to pass?

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so we may best assist you here.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12024498/10974490) answer your question?

Comment: @BartBarnard If you feel another question's answers answer the question, feel free to flag the question as a duplicate of that other question. No need for a comment, unless you want to.