# Object not defined when eventlistener i triggered

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
span {
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
}  
span:hover {
  display: fit-content;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span>3.1415</span>
</body>
<script>
  function setBckCol(col) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = col;
  }
  function setSpanListeners() {
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    for(var i = 0; i < spans.length ;i++) {
      spans[i].addEventListener('click', setBckCol('#F9E79F'));                    
    }
 }
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("span");
for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  nodeList[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
setSpanListeners();
</script>
</html>
```

I am getting the error message in Chrome developer tools when executing the script. The error refers to line 21, see the attached image.

[image: Snippet from Chrome developer toools]

Seems "this" is not passed to the setBckCol function. How to correct it?

Comment: what is this referring to?

Comment: Thanks. I was put off by this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024483/how-to-pass-parameter-to-function-using-in-addeventlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are only passing color to the setbckcol `setBckCol('#F9E79F')` instead you have to pass the element & the color.`setBckCol(spans[i],'#F9E79F')`.

also have to collect both of them `function setBckCol(el,col)`

```js
function setBckCol(el,col) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = col;
}

function setSpanListeners() {
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].addEventListener('click', setBckCol(spans[i],'#F9E79F'));
  }
}
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("span");
for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  nodeList[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
setSpanListeners();
```

```css
span {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span:hover {
  display: fit-content;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span>3.1415</span>
  <span>3.1415</span>
</body>
>
```